# Add objects to array in ruby loop persists latest object to all array items

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

The following code demonstrates a ruby (1.8.7) for loop in which a column and header read in from excel are saved as an object (object attributes: header=string, contents=array of strings). As I'm reading in several columns I want to save them as an array of objects.

The issue is that each loop, while incrementing the array 'matrix', and successfully storing the new object, seems to overwrite the previous elements of the matrix array with the newest object. When I iterate through the finished array, I just get x instances of the same object.

```
  column_count = count_columns(worksheet)
  row_count = count_rows(worksheet)

  matrix = Array.new
  #i don't think header needs to be an array in the below loop, but anyway...
  header = Array.new
  contents = Array.new

  for column in 0..column_count - 1
    header[column] = worksheet.Cells(1, column + 2).Value
    for row in 0..row_count
      contents[row] = worksheet.Cells(row + 2, column + 2).Value
    end
    matrix[column] = Worksheet_Column.new(header[column], contents)
  end


  #looping after the array was created puts the same information in each iteration
  for column in 0..matrix.length - 1
    puts "loop = #{column}"

    puts matrix[column]
  end
```

Comment: please work with `.each` and `.each_with_index`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't see what elementary mistake allowed the contents to write backward, but having noticed the problem occurred for the contents and not for the header this solution has been successful.

```
for column in 0..column_count - 1
  contents[column] = Array.new
  header[column] = worksheet.Cells(1, column + 2).Value
  for row in 0..row_count
    contents[column][row] = worksheet.Cells(row + 2, column + 2).Value
  end
  matrix[column] = Worksheet_Column.new(header[column], contents[column])
end
```